# How to get information about current user distribution list from outlook using WPF business app

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook

In my WPF app, I need to enable/disable functionality based on the team. The team information is configured as outlook distribution list. Now I need retrieve this information from my App.

I googled and found the link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff184638(v=office.15).aspx

Unfortunately it doesn't compile as it is. After bit of research I can make it compile by changing it by changing it as

```
             currentUser = new Outlook.Application().Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
```

However, this works only when outlook is opened, but when outlook is closed it throws the exception. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I managed to crack it. Apparently we need to briefly start the outlook application, the solution is explained in the link
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.outlook.program_vba/lLJwbwwl-XU/gRuQYRpJtxEJ

Hence I modified my code GetCurrentUserMembership() slightly to accomadate this change. Now it's working  good. Tested in outlook 2007 and 2010.

The complete solution,

```
  private List<string> GetCurrentUserMembership()
    {
        Outlook.Application outlook = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)outlook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        Outlook.Inspector oInspector = oMsg.GetInspector;

        //session.Logon("", "", false, false);
        var sb = new List<string>();
        Outlook.AddressEntry currentUser = outlook.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
        if (currentUser.Type != "EX") return sb;

        var exchUser = currentUser.GetExchangeUser();

        if (exchUser == null) return sb;

        var addrEntries = exchUser.GetMemberOfList();
        if (addrEntries == null) return sb;

        foreach (Outlook.AddressEntry addrEntry in addrEntries)
        {
            sb.Add(addrEntry.Name);
        }
        return sb;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please be more specific? What exception (error message and error code) do you get in the code?

I'd recommend starting from breaking the chain of calls and declare each property or method call on a separate line. Thus, you will find a problematic property or method call which fires an exception.

Most probably you need to call the Logon method of the Namespace class. As an example, you may find the [C# app automates Outlook (CSAutomateOutlook)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateOutlook-a3b7bdc9) sample project helpful.

Comment: I am getting exception System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException.As i mentioned in my mail it works when outlook is opened, but throws this exception when outlook is closed

Comment: What property or method exactly fires the exception?

Comment: Do you have a default profile set without a password? Did you have a chance to check the list of running processes? Is there Outlook.exe?

Comment: thanks for your time i managed to crack by myself,pls see the below post

Comment: But you you had an exception at the Logon method, am I wrong?

Comment: i did indeed. Earlier without logon i could not able to get data's. But now I changed the implementation as below.The trouble is, the example given in msdn is for outlook add on, where it has the exchange server connection(my understanding). but when we try to access from externl app some how we need to connect to exchange server first.